# Mailboxer: recipient inbox not showing conversations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailboxer

On the product listing page of my marketplace, I've create a button the send a message to the user of each product, with the link_to:

```
<%= link_to "Contact", new_conversation_path(recipient_id: product.user.id) %>
```

Here is my converations_controller:

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!



def index
@conversations = current_user.mailbox.conversations
end

def show
@conversation = current_user.mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])
end

def new

 
@recipient = User.find(params[:recipient_id])
end

def create
recipient = User.find(params[:recipient_id]).id
receipt = current_user.send_message(@recipient, params[:body], params[:subject])
redirect_to conversation_path(receipt.conversation)
end

end
```

My new conversation page:

```
<h1>New conversation</h1>


<%= form_tag conversations_path, method: :post do %>
<div>

</div>

<div>
<%= text_field_tag :subject, nil, placeholder: "Subject" %>
</div>

<div>
<%= text_area_tag :body, nil, placeholder: "Your message" %>
</div>


<%= submit_tag "Send",:class=>"btn btn-warning" %>

<% end %>
```

When I click on the link to send a message I am correctly redirect to the "conversation new" page, which has on its URL:

```
/conversations/new?recipient_id=7
```

With the id of the correct user id, but when I send the message,

I have the following error:

> couldn't find user with 'id'=

Comment: When you say conversations page of the user 7, do you mean conversations `show.html.erb`?

Comment: No i mean on the index of the conversations page. I think the problem belong to recipient not being associated correctly because, on the sender conversation index, you can see the conversation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make it working finally, here is my code, maybe it can help other:

(i'm on rails 5)

The link on my product page:

```
<%= link_to "Contactar", new_conversation_path(recipient_id: service.user.id) %>
```

My new and create action on my conversation controller:

```
 def new
 @recipients = User.find(params[:recipient_id])

 end

 def create
 recipient = User.find_by(id: params[:recipient_id])
 receipt = current_user.send_message(recipient, params[:body],    params[:subject])
 redirect_to conversation_path(receipt.conversation)
 end
```

On the new conversation:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag(:recipient_id, "#{@recipients.id}") %>
```